# DijanError during template rendering Dijango 1.6

Tags: python, django

I am try to do , project using django 1.6. but below code line 5 pass  error.without that line every thing work fine. I am new programmer. expect some expert help.

```
1   {% extends "base.html" %}
2   
3   {% block content %}
4       {% for post in posts_list %}
5         <h2><a href="{% url post slug=post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
6         <p>{{ post.body|truncatewords:20 }}</p>
7         <p>
8           {{ post.created_at }} |
9           {% with total=post.comments|length %}
10              {{ total }} comment{{ total|pluralize }}
11          {% endwith %}
12        </p>
13      {% endfor %}
14  {% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
        queryset=Post.objects.all(),
        context_object_name="posts_list"),
        name="home"
    ),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$', DetailView.as_view(
        queryset=Post.objects.all(),
        context_object_name="post"),
        name="post"
    ),
)
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField, EmbeddedModelField


class Post(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedModelField('Comment'), editable=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_at"]


class Comment(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name="Comment")
    author = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=255)
```

If you want , I will supply further details.

===============full traceback=========================================

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.6.11
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django_mongodb_engine',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'marcador')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/test2/marcador/templates/marcador/post_list.html, error at line 5
   coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Post found
   1 : {% extends "base.html" %}


   2 : 


   3 : {% block content %}


   4 :     {% for post in posts_list %}


   5 :       <h2><a href=" {% url post slug=post.slug %} ">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>


   6 :       <p>{{ post.body|truncatewords:20 }}</p>


   7 :       <p>


   8 :         {{ post.created_at }} |


   9 :         {% with total=post.comments|length %}


   10 :             {{ total }} comment{{ total|pluralize }}


   11 :         {% endwith %}


   12 :       </p>


   13 :     {% endfor %}


   14 : {% endblock %}

Traceback:
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  137.                 response = response.render()
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  82.         content = template.render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  196.                         nodelist.append(node.render(context))
File "/home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/myprojec/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  439.                     url = reverse(project_name + '.' + view_name,

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Post found
```

Comment: Please post the complete traceback.

Comment: @RahulGupta , I think ,you expect think , i added to question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, **you have missed to put the quotes around `post`** in `{% url post slug=post.slug %}`.

When you do `{% url post slug=post.slug %}` the value of `post` passed is the `Post` object from the `for` loop in the template and not the url with name `post`. This can be found out by the error `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Post found` which mentions that a `Post` object was found.

To resolve your issue, you need to use  quotes around `post` in your `url` tag so that it uses the url with reverse name as `'post'`.

```
{% url 'post' slug=post.slug %}
```

Comment: Thank you , very much. I too up-vote your answer. :-) . it is very help full , to me understanding. please ,do you know any article so , good for reading ,please , put me link.

Comment: @uma You can check out the resources and books mentioned here on the official SO django tag's [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/django/info)

Answer (score 4):

Try change this:

```
<h2><a href="{% url post slug=post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
```

To:

```
<h2><a href="{% url 'post' slug=post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
```

> Template error: In template
>   /home/umayanga/Desktop/mongoProject/test2/marcador/templates/marcador/post_list.html,
>   error at line 5    coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Post
>   found

The problem, he was expect a namespaced URL : [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url),
and you are pass a POST, object instead of 'post' namespace.

Comment: @PauloPessoa You are right. It seems the OP has missed to put quotes around `post` in the url tag which led to `post` object of the for loop being used. Updated my ans.

Comment: Thank you..! both of you , I am new comer to dijango programming , so these day I faced lot of problems . now , one is correct.